# How to use aggregate function like sum and avg on entire column except first few rows after sorting in Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

For example,my table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
| TOTAL  NUMBER  NAME |
+---------------------+
| 10        5       A |
| 5         8       A |
| 21        32      A |
| 7         3       A |
| 7         3       B |
| 11        5       B |
| 5         8       B |
| 21        32      B |
+---------------------+
```

After sorting by NUMBER:

```
+---------------------+
| TOTAL  NUMBER  NAME |
+---------------------+
| 7         3       A |
| 7         3       B |
| 10        5       A |
| 11        5       B |
| 5         8       A |
| 5         8       B |
| 21        32      A |
| 21        32      B |
+---------------------+
```

And I only want the sum of total of first two rows of each group grouping by NAME:

```
A  7+10=17
B  7+11=18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be something like:

```
select sum(total),name from
(select Total, name from 
table order by number where name = 'A' FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY 
 union select Total, name from 
table order by number where name = 'B' FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY )dt group by name
```

In derived table top 2 result will be selected ordered by column number and the outer query will add the total values.

EDIT: The foloowing query should do your job.

```
SELECT name,sum(total)
FROM   table s
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    table t
            WHERE t.name = s.name AND 
                  t.number >= s.number
        ) <= 2
 group by name;
```

Comment: I use derby , sorry for my inappropriate example . Please wait a minute.

Comment: But I have more than 400 different names…Is using a loop to generate a statement the only way to achieve this？